# Downloading and Transferring Files Simultaneously with Limited EC2 Storage

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using an EC2 instance in AWS to run a bash script that downloads files from a server using a CLI while simultaneously moving them into S3 using the AWS CLI (aws s3 mv). However, I usually run out of storage before I can do this because the download speeds are faster than the transfer speeds to S3.  The files, which are downloaded daily, are usually hundreds of GB and I do not want to upgrade storage capacity if at all possible.

The CLI I am using for the downloads runs continuously until success/fail but outputs statuses to the console (when I run it from command line instead of .sh) as it goes.  I am looking for a way to theoretically run this script based on the specifications given. My most recent attempt was to use something long the lines of:

```
until (CLI_is_downloading) | grep -m 1 "download complete"; do aws s3 mv --recursive path/local_memory s3://path/s3; done
```

But that ran out of memory and the download failed well before the move was finished.

Some possible solutions that I thought of are to somehow run the download CLI until I reach a certain point of memory available before switching to the transfer and then alternating back and forth.  Also, I am not too experienced with AWS so I am not sure this would work, but could I limit the download speed to match the transfer speed (like network throttling)?  Any advice on the practicality of my ideas or other suggestions on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I checked my console output again and it seems that the aws s3 mv --recursive only moved the files that were currently there when the function was first called and then stopped.  I believe if I called it repeatedly until I got my "files downloaded" message from my other CLI command, it might work. I am not sure exactly how to do this yet so suggestions would still be appreciated but otherwise, this seems like a job for tomorrow.

Comment: Do you mean that you run out of diskspace (rather than memory)?

Comment: Yes storage.  I changed my question to better reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: If you're only running this daily could you temporarily create and attach a large EBS volume, use it, and then delete it?  Depending on your throughput needs you could look at Throughput Optimized HDD (st1) or Cold HDD (sc1) devices which, while slower, are pretty cheap.